# How To Use libGLESv2.so in Your Program

Tags: opengl-es, dynamic-linking, glx

I am accustomed to linking against libGL.so on most Linux distributions. Either mesa's implementation or NVIDIA's. However, I would really like to limit myself to OpenGL ES 2.X functionality, so I am attempting to link against and use libGLESv2.so. However, I see that glX functions are not present in libGLESv2.so dynamic section:

```
nm --dynamic /usr/lib64/nvidia/libGLESv2.so | grep glX
```

Also attempting to link agains libGLESv2.so results in undefined references to glX functions.

This leads me to my question. What is the correct way to "GetProcAddress" while dynamically linking against libGLESv2.so? Also how do you construct the appropriate context without glX?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how easy this will be for you to figure out and how relevant for your applications but in pi3d we get the drawing context using libEGL.so (or libegl.dll from ANGLE on windows).

This where the dynamic libraries are found and loaded

[https://github.com/tipam/pi3d/blob/master/pi3d/constants/**init**.py](https://github.com/tipam/pi3d/blob/master/pi3d/constants/__init__.py)

and this is where the surface is created and attached to the GLESv2 functions

https://github.com/tipam/pi3d/blob/master/pi3d/util/DisplayOpenGL.py